# Making an ArrayFormula from QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs, array-formulas

How do I convert this:

```
=if(ISNA(sum(QUERY(importrange("1QNYU1Kb1rtx-n4tMRamHJuvYt_9kGMfhGZZs_opuJr0","Transfer!C$2:E"),"SELECT Col3 WHERE Col1 = '" & Sheet1!B$2:B & "' ",0))),"0",sum(QUERY(importrange("1QNYU1Kb1rtx-n4tMRamHJuvYt_9kGMfhGZZs_opuJr0","Transfer!C$2:E"),"SELECT Col3 WHERE Col1 = '" & Sheet1!B$2:B & "' ",0)))
```

into the array formula in Google Sheets?

Comment: Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WwWqZMexma0Sf_6s4yoOPyC2dzFl6mRWNsjPbqAccvs/edit?usp=drivesdk. The expression was needed as the 'Delivered Qty' column header.

Comment: And this is the reference sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QNYU1Kb1rtx-n4tMRamHJuvYt_9kGMfhGZZs_opuJr0/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Opps.. Sharing setting has been updated.

The 'MO Listing" worksheet 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WwWqZMexma0Sf_6s4yoOPyC2dzFl6mRWNsjPbqAccvs'

 required an arrayformula to do a SUMIF links to another worksheet, Transfer!E:E 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QNYU1Kb1rtx-n4tMRamHJuvYt_9kGMfhGZZs_opuJr0/edit?usp=sharing' referred by "MO Listing' B2:B 'MO No'.

Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Thanks player0. I thought arrayformula should be in the header row since the data set will change?

Comment: yup, but you locked all cells in header row so I put it under header row. feel free to move it

Comment: Thank you for your response player0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion, it would be pretty much an overkill if it would be possible. instead I recon to do this:

- use side columns (or create a new sheet in `PRC Records` spreadsheet) and paste this formula **[there](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QNYU1Kb1rtx-n4tMRamHJuvYt_9kGMfhGZZs_opuJr0/edit#gid=1162059791)**:

---

```
=QUERY({Transfer!A1:H}, "select Col3, sum(Col5) 
                         where Col3 is not null 
                         group by Col3 
                         label sum(Col5)'FG Qty'", 1)
```

[image: 0]

- and then use this formula in **J2** cell over on the `MO Listing` **[spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WwWqZMexma0Sf_6s4yoOPyC2dzFl6mRWNsjPbqAccvs/edit#gid=0)**:

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1QNYU1Kb1rtx-n4tMRamHJuvYt_9kGMfhGZZs_opuJr0", 
             "Transfer!L2:M"), 2, 0), 0), ))
```

[image]